# How to use JavaScript geolocation object passed to PHP from an HTML form

Tags: javascript, php, sql, sqlite

I am using JavaScript to access the Geolocation API to obtain the position of the device and make it the value attribute of an HTML form input element. When the form is submitted it posts the position object to the script. I want to use PHP to store the object in an SQL database (SQLite). Also I want to be able to access information from within the object either before putting it in the database or after getting it back out of the database using PHP. At the moment I can not put the object in the database or get information out of it.

The (simplified) code I am using is given here:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
  echo '<p>'.$_POST['position'].'</p>';
}
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>HTML Template</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method='post'>
  <div id='div1'>
  </div>
  <script>
      const success = (position) => {
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.setAttribute("name", "position");
        input.setAttribute("type", "text");
        input.setAttribute("value", position);
        var element = document.getElementById("div1");
        element.appendChild(input);
      }
      var id = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
    </script>
  <input type='submit' value='submit'>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this in a browser and allow sharing of my position it creates an input field with [object GeolocationPosition] in it. When I then submit the form it echoes out the same [object GeolocationPosition].

If I 'unpack' the object using JavaScript before assigning it to the form input's attribute value then I can use the information with PHP when the form is submitted. However this seems a complicated and error prone approach compared to putting the whole object in the database.

I would appreciate some pointers please.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "GeolocationPosition" is still an object. Run `console.log("GeolocationPosition");` to return all of it's properties in the console.

For instance, if you are trying to get, lets say the latitude you could use `GeolocationPosition["lat"]` (if the property "lat" exsists)

Comment: I can get the data out of the object if I use console.log() or other javascript. I can't get the data out of the object when I use PHP. I want to use PHP to access the object once it has been posted back to my script.